# React Navigation AddListener Not working Correctly

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I am trying to deepLinking and catching the url when url open the page on the screen which is functionally works when my app is not working on the background. However, it doesn't work if app is working on the background.

```
const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  useEffect(() => {
    getCode();
  }, [isFocused]);

  const getCode = async () => {
    //we will generate a button in the forget password email, link will include a url ===> mobile://auth/new-password?verification=534396
    const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
    console.log('url', url);
    if (url?.includes('new-password')) {
      //problem, it may not work if app is still working on the background
      const query = queryString.parseUrl(url);
      const verifyCode = query.query.verification;
      setVerificationCode(String(verifyCode));
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Something went wrong');
    }
  };
```

When I directlinked to application with the link, it console log as "url null". Is my problem on the focusing part or on the getInitialUrl function?

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing a similar issue.

In my case we used `linking` from [NavigationContainer](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container#linking) and it would open the same `X` screen left on background regardless if the deeplink data had a different value for that screen.

I fixed it by using the `getId` on `Stack.Screen`:

```
const getId = ({ params }) => params?.id;

<Stack.Screen name="X" component={XComponent} getId={getId} />
```

You can find more info on `getId` here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen/#getid.